# how to access variables inside a for loop and if statement and print or insert inside the json in python

Tags: python, json, for-loop, if-statement, key-value

I want to iterate through the json array and use for loop compare the values by using if statement and store them in a variable and use it further.when I am trying to print json it saying one and two is not defined am new to python please help me.

```
data = {"usa":["alabama","georgia","texas","florida"]}

for value in data['usa']:
    if value == alabama:
        one = value
    elif value == texas:
        two = value

json = {"states":one,"mystate":two}
    print(json)
```

My output should be like this

```
{"state":alabama, "mystate":texas}
```

I want to use the one and two variables to insert or print inside the json and use it for another purpose.

Comment: Compare to strings : `if value == 'alabama':` | `elif value == 'texas':`

Comment: if I do like that if value == 'alabama': | elif value == 'texas' how should i use in my json which value to print? {"state":value, "mystate":value} it doesnt know which value to print in the json? so thats why i want o differentiate the each value.please help me how to differentiate each value and store it in a variable and how can i use those variables outside the for loop @jacobIRR

Comment: @rick just do as you're doing now, but with quotes around `alabama` and `texas`. As your code is now, your script will throw an error over an undefined variable.

Comment: @RobinZigmond am not clear what you said. that's my expected output which am not getting now. if i do json = {"states":one,"mystate":two} the output should be like this {"state":"alabama", "mystate":"texas"} but am getting an error saying one and two are not defined.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having trouble understanding why you want to do it like this, but I think what you want to do is this:

```
data = {"usa":["alabama","georgia","texas","florida"]}

for value in data['usa']:
    if value == 'alabama':
        one = value
    elif value == 'texas':
        two = value

json = {"states":one,"mystate":two}
print(json)
```

---

If you are worried about `'alabama'` and `'texas'` not being in the list, you could do something that defines `one` and `two` before hand:

```
data = {"usa":["alabama","georgia","texas","florida"]}

one = 'Not in list'
two = 'Not in list'

for value in data['usa']:
    if value == 'alabama':
        one = value
    elif value == 'texas':
        two = value

json = {"states":one,"mystate":two}
print(json)
```

Comment: yes i want to do like that but am getting an error saying "one"  and "two" is not defined. am thinking is it because those are inside the loop so that i cannot use outside? please help me how can i use those variables outside the loop ?@Stephen

Comment: You can use them outside the loop, but if they weren't in `data['usa']` _then_ they won't be defined. See my edit to the post @rick

Comment: yes I already tried in that way but still giving the error No JSON object could be decoded. am not understanding were the error is and what to do?

Comment: @rick I think I would need to see a little more of your code.... Are you using it for a server? Or are you trying to save the dict as a json file? Or....

Comment: actually my code is like this   data = {"usa":["alabama.rick123.la","texas.456.ca","georgia","florida"]}
id = os.getenv(123) #getting from jenkins parameters
id1 = os.getenv(456)  #getting from jenkins parameters                                                                                  one = 'Not in list'
two = 'Not in list'

for value in data['usa']:
    if value == "alabama'" + .rick+os.getenv(id)+".la":
        one = value
    elif value == "texas."+os.getenv(id1)+".ca"
        two = value 
json = {"states":one,"mystate":two}
print(json) getting No JSON obeject to decode

Comment: am using it as a Jenkins script @Stephen